# how do run syncdb without loading fixtures?

Tags: python, django, django-models

is there a way to run syncdb without loading fixtures?
xo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rename the fixture to something else than initial_data

Comment: But what if you wanted that initial data loaded when running "manage.py test"?

Answer (score 12):

`./manage.py help syncdb` suggests the following:

```
./manage.py syncdb --no-initial-data
```

From [Django docs on initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/):

If you create a fixture named `initial_data.[xml/yaml/json]`, that fixture will be loaded every time you run `migrate`. This is extremely convenient, but be careful: remember that the data will be refreshed *every* time you run `migrate`. So don’t use initial_data for data you’ll want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

best to name your fixtures something_else.json, then run syncdb (and migrate if needed), followed by manage.py loaddata something_else.json